# Как завершить программу через определенное время, заданное пользователем?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#Говнокод, просто демонстрирующий то, чего я бы хотел добиться.

print "Please input time, which will used for kill a current of process\n";
my $time = <>;
chomp $time;
print "You input $time seconds\n";
print "Current process will be killed after $time seconds\n";
print "Please input any command\n";
my $command = <>;
```

Собственно, вопрос: Пользователю в любом случае необходимо будет ввести время (в секундах), по истечению которого PID программы должен убиться. В общем, я понимаю,  что в перле есть `$$`, но  как его связать с секундами, введённые пользователям и убить процесс - я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна стандартная функция [alarm](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html). В документации есть готовый пример. Адаптируем

```
my $command;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n обязателен
    alarm $timeout;
    # теперь собственно ввод пользователя
    $command = <>;
    # надо сбросить, что бы программу случайно не прибило.
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # завершим работу, если не таймаут
    # обработаем таймаут
    say "ваше время истекло";
}
else {
    # а сюда попадем, если все ок.
}
```